# How do I use a variable within a selector?

Tags: css-selectors, less

I'm having a problem with that variables in some cases are not set correctly.

```
@index: 10;
[data-grid*='cols-@{index}'] > * {
    background: red;
}
```

I use a variable `index` with the value of 10. I would expect the `@{index}` to be replaced with 10 but it doesn't. The result is `[data-grid*='cols-@{index}']` and I don't get any errors.

Maybe I need to escape it somehow?

Comment: For future visitors - the code in question would compile perfectly fine in the latest version of Less compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You kind of answered your own question: You should treat the whole selector as a string. This seems to work:

```
@index: 10;
(~"[data-grid*='cols-@{index}'] > *")
{
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: I just found out that this works: (~".myclass_@{index}") and I still think it's possible in my case as well.